# Git: summarize sub-repos

Tags: git, maven

Lets say I have multiple standalone subprojects with its own pom.xml and git-repo.
But now I assemble them together in a project X.

```
project X
 - sub A
 - sub B
 - sub C
```

I want to generate all subprojects in X. I do that with a pom.xml that has the projects A to C as modules. Generation of X would generalte all projects. 
Works fine!

Is there a way I can summarize the git-repos together too?
A commit in X should perform the commit in every projekt. Same for update, ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### git-submodule-foreach

`git submodule` provides a utility to iterate through all submodules:

The command to execute `git commit` in every submodule within the current project is as follows:

`git submodule foreach "git commit"`

### git-foreach

As a convenience, I made a simple bash script that runs an arbitrary command in the current project plus all of it's submodules. This way I don't have to type the command twice (once for the parent-project then again for git-submodule-foreach)

### *~/bin/git-foreach*

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
if [ "$*" == "" ]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 COMMAND"
    echo
    echo "Run an arbitrary COMMAND in the current git repository plus all of the submodules"
    echo
    exit 1
fi
echo "Entering '.'"
# run the command in PWD
"$@"

# now run the command on submodules
git submodule foreach "$*"
```

Place the `git-foreach` executable somewhere in your `$PATH` and run it from within a git repo:

```
# describe the commit at HEAD for the project and all subprojects:
git foreach git describe
```

Answer (score 0):

git has no concept of "subprojects" as Maven does.

To accomplish what you want, I have a (bash) function setup on my machine:

```
git-all () 
{ 
  find ~/workspace -name .git -type d -print -execdir git "$@" \;
}
```

The find command:

- looks through all folders (local repositories), in my ~/workspace
- finds any directory named .git
- prints out the path
- at that path executes git command followed by the rest of my arguments

So then I can do something like:

```
git-all commit -m "my commit"
```